# Выбрать из ответа Ajax элемент по классу

Tags: ajax, javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://www.site.ru",
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
                   success: function(data) {
                        console.log($(data).find('.need_you'));
                   }
});
```

Хочу получить со страницы http://www.site.ru  jQuery-объект элемента .need_you в таком виде примерно:

```
<div class="need_you">123</div>
```

Как если бы мы его получили на целевой странице:

```
$('.need_you');
```

Вместо этого в консоли появляется какой то стремный объект, на который смотреть страшно. Подозреваю что косяк в том, что ответ мне пришел в виде строки. Прошу подсказать как грамотно преобразовать ответ в дерево, чтобы можно было работать с набором элементов?

Возвращаемый объект:

```
Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bH.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
isRejected: function (){return!!e}
isResolved: function (){return!!e}
overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 4
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html><html >******Здесь весь HTML страницы построчно******</body></html>"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
state: function (){return e}
status: 200
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
statusText: "OK"
success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log($(data).find('.need_you').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
console.log($(data.responseText).filter('.need_you').html());
```

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое что и в ответе выше.

Comment: покажите что вам приходит в ответ

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Возвращает тот же объект, что в вопросе. Как и в случае console.log($(data.responseText))